# iptables rules not reloading on CentOS 6.x

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, reboot, ipset

I have one single ipset added to my `iptables` on a CentOS 6.x box and this rule is lost when the machine reboots.

I've found **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91413/reloading-iptables/243180#243180)** showing how to make a Ubuntu system reload the `iptables` rules after a reboot but this directory is not present on CentOS.

How do I make this CentOS box load the firewall rules after a reboot?

**NOTE:** Yes, I'm saving the rules using `iptables save` and the file is being saved.

This is what is inside `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Apr  8 09:52:59 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2713:308071]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1649:1766437]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,465,110,143,993,995 -m state --state INVALID,NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m set
 --match-set blocking src -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr  8 09:52:59 2013
```

the command shows `-A INPUT` but when I created it I have used `-I INPUT`.

The rule used to create this was:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,465,110,143,993,995 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED,INVALID -m set --set blocking src -j DROP
```

Comment: @Christopher, sounds similar to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-* files.  Does this ipset file contain definitions of ipset data structures or actual iptables rules?  Example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost rules because:

> After adding rules you have to do save before restart service or server. because when you add rule, they are in memory but after saving they will save in file and restore from that file at start-up.

So first You need to save added rules using:

```
$ /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

This will save all rules in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, then just enable the iptables service at start-up using:

```
$ chkconfig --level 53 iptables on
```

#### Method 2

To save rules:

```
$ /sbin/iptables-save  > /etc/iptables.rules
```

To restore rules [ Add Below entry in `/etc/rc.local` ]:

```
$ /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rule
```

Comment: I did that and iptables loads when the system starts, but it loads empty.

Comment: have you checked `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file ?

Comment: after adding rule just do `save ` which I mention above , then it will restore at start-up using `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file

Comment: Yes, the file is saved correctly. This is something weird I discovered now: when I do *service iptables save* I see a message telling me that the rules were saved to /etc/sysconfig/iptables but when I do your command */etc/init.d/iptables save* the message tells me that the rules were saved to /etc/sysconfig/ipt. In other words, saved to a different file... why is that?

Comment: both are same `service iptables save` both refer same init file i.e `/etc/init.d/iptables`

Comment: so, we are back to square 1. The file is saved correctly but when the system starts iptables is loaded empty.

Comment: After adding rules you have to do save before restart service or server. because when you add rule, they are in memory but after saving they will save in file and restore from that file at start-up\

Comment: yes, I know that. The rules are there saved to /etc/sysconfig/iptables but they are not being loaded.

Comment: check rule are added or not using `iptables -L -n -v`

Comment: if rule are listed , and not able to save then you can save it manually using `iptable-save >> /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Comment: I have added more information to the question.

Comment: @DigitalRobot I have added another method for the same, also check iptables service is enable at startup using `chkconfig --list | grep iptables` and also check errors in logs

Comment: I have tried your methods. No change. iptables starts but does not load the rules. Apparently /etc/rc.local is not running either. What logs should I check for errors?

Comment: give me output of `chkconfig --list | grep iptables`

Comment: if issue not solve , then disable SElinux and check it again , refer this link for disable SElinux http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-check-and-disable-selinux-on-centos-6-3/

Comment: iptables        0:no 1:no 2:yes 3:yes 4:yes 5:yes 6:no     and SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: seems fine with rule level, have you disabled SElinux and checked ? , you must reboot system after disable SElinux

Comment: SELinux status:                 disabled  I have not disabled it. It was already disabled.

Comment: Sorry for late reply , Is your issue solve ? if not just let me know your Rule is restored or not  using `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rule`

Comment: nope. The rules are not reloaded after boot. I solved that temporarily by created a crontab that runs a bash script that tests if there are any rules loaded and loads them in not. It is a lame solution, but it is working until I discover a real solution. Thanks.

Comment: @DigitalRobot Recently I uninstall CentOs6 and Install CentOs5.9 for better stability , and avoid new issues[I wast 1 hour for mysql password recovery because of CentOs6, I think 6 series not ready for production]

Comment: This is the only problem with 6 I had so far. I will keep an eye.

Comment: The file is clearly already saved as proven in the question itself "This is what is inside /etc/sysconfig/iptables" , the problem is with ipset.  When iptables restores from a file but that file contains unknown ipset sets, no iptables are restored at all.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem.

You have created a `set` with ipset called "blocking", however, I don't see where this `set` gets saved so you'd have to recreate it after ever reboot in a script I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed the same issue on Centos 6.4.

I've just put `@reboot /etc/init.d/iptables restart` in the crontab and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to Host Gator and I finally got a response from a Linux Administrator at Host Gator:

> Hello there!
>
> HostGator has built a custom firewall that's in place by default on all VPS and dedicated server plans.
>
> Luckliy, there is a file in the firewall configuration that is meant to persist iptables configurations.
>
> The file is this: `/etc/firewall/INCLUDE`
>
> Just add your iptables lines to that file, and restart the firewall with service firewall restart. The iptables rules will persist.
>
> Actually, I've gone ahead and added those lines to the file, so your iptables rules should load and persist now.
>
> Please don't hesitate to follow up if you have any more questions or concerns